# Open SQLite db in Microsoft Access?

Tags: microsoft-access, sqlite

Are there any tools to allow using sqlite databases from Microsoft Access?

Of course full access is preferred, being able to edit records, add tables & fields, etc. but read-only browsing would helpful too.

I'm using Access 2007 x64.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you want is an ODBC driver for SQLite...

Such as:

- http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/

Just googling for "SQLite ODBC" returns a heap of results that can help you.

Comment: thanks for ODBC keyword. I'm as yet unable to get sqliteodbc to work, *"The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application (#0)"*, but at least now I have a path to follow.

Comment: @mattwilkie Were you able to get this working?

Comment: @Forethinker, yes, though the details are lost in time and I've not used the connection for quite awhile. It was through reading and testing the linke above though.

Comment: For people finding this through Google, I had the mismatch architecture problem when the sqliteodbc version was a different architecture (32bit vs 64bit) to MS Office, not to the OS it's installed on. ie installing 64bit ODBC on 64bit windows won't work with 32bit Office.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using access, I wrote a SQL browser for access called [PlaneDisaster.NET](http://plane-disaster.sourceforge.net/).  I also have a tool in there that converts from mdb to sqlite. I never wrote a tool to go the other way, but if you know C# that code is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm aware not specifically answering your question, you might also consider Kexi (www.kexi-project.org), which is an Access-like or Framemaker-like software and natively using sqlite.
It was initially written for Linux with KDE Destkop, but was compiled to a binary for Windows too (https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=221&t=110012) and Kexi's main author is currently paying attention to the native Window port (https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=220&t=127422).