# How can I edit a keyword search in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, search, bookmarks

I have several "keyword searches" set up in Chrome (added by right-clicking in a search box on a site, and selecting "add as search engine.").

I'm fairly certain these used to be saved as bookmarks (I remember it asking me where to save the bookmark) which could be viewed in the bookmark manager.  However now, I can't find them anywhere.

I'd like to edit the text string saved on one of them - how can I do this?

EDIT:  I see that they are [stored in an SQLite file](https://superuser.com/questions/272511/where-do-chrome-chromium-store-search-keywords) but this is not easily editable.  Is there a way to edit them from within Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can edit search engines in Chrome Settings. There you can add/edit and change saved search engines and their keywords.

Is that what you needed?

Comment: Yes, thank you!  I didn't think that they were considered "search engines."