# Backup and restore Chrome search engine settings

Tags: google-chrome, search

I'm using Chrome search engines chrome://settings/searchEngines for both shortcuts and personalized search with some predefined properties.

Unfortunately, recently I cleaned trash off search engines list and accidentally removed some of my custom shortcuts and hand-made "search engines". Is there any way to recover them?

[image]

I even have backup of my profile, but I found not where search engines are stored to restore them separately from other settings. So it seems I have to manually compare and copy-paste strings of search engines I want to get back.

(note that screenshot shows search engines in my work profile, and there are far fewer engines comparing to my private profile)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where do chrome/chromium store search keywords?](https://superuser.com/questions/272511/where-do-chrome-chromium-store-search-keywords)

Comment: except my question was asked in 2016, and the one you linked – in 2018 :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A crude way to do this is to keep a copy of Chrome's "Web Data" file located in
`Username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`.

Comment: It's a `.sqlite`file that can be open with something like http://sqlitebrowser.org/. The search engine are in the table `keywords`

Comment: Pardon my noob question as I have never used SQLite before. I used the browser, clicked into keywords table but do not see my custom search engine. Where exactly should I go to see my custom engines?

https://i.imgur.com/MbqjVeG.png

Answer (score 2):

i was able to accomplish this on chrome v86.0.x , today (oct 2020),  between two win10 PCs (one is my old pc, one is the new pc im building)-

by using the app from sqlitebrowser.org  , to export just the "keywords" table to a .csv (from the "Web Data" file/sqlite db of the "old" chrome)

then on the new PC/chrome, i opened the "new" chrome's Web Data sqlite db, and deleted the "keywords" table, and imported the .csv (from step1).
its important that you check off "Column Names in first line"  when importing the csv. (see photo , also the table name ofcourse has to = keywords)

[image]

after doing this, on the new pc + chrome i was able to use my search keywords.  (ie a common one i use is,  "ebs" (tab) searchTerm , which searches ebay's **sold** items

Edit- not sure if this is relevant, but i do NOT use chrome/google's Sync-Chrome-Settings-to-Cloud feature, in chrome.